# Java Decimal to Hexadecimal Program

Tags: java, netbeans

Question: (Decimal to hex) Write a program that prompts the user to enter an integer between
0 and 15 and displays its corresponding hex number. Here are some sample runs:

Enter a decimal value (0 to 15): 11
The hex value is B

Enter a decimal value (0 to 15): 5
The hex value is 5

Enter a decimal value (0 to 15): 31
31 is an invalid input

The below is my code. 1. I don't truly understand `charAt(0)` nor what it is I'm doing wrong. 1-9=1-9 and 10-15=A-F. I can only use what is seen in the code. No special `toHexStrings` `cases` or `arrays`. This is the basics of the basics. I don't understand why RULE1 is being ignored, or if there are more problems.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NewClass1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {              
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a decimal value (0 to 15): ");
        String decimal = input.nextLine();

    // RULE1 
        char ch = decimal.charAt(0);
        if (ch <= 15 && ch >= 10) {
             System.out.println("The hex value is " + (char)ch);
        }

    // RULE2
        else if (ch <= 10 && ch >= 0) {
                System.out.println("Tsshe hex value is " + ch);
        }

    // RULE3
        else {
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
        }
    }
}
```

RULE1 is being ignored and I can't see why. It's 2 in the morning and I've been at this for 4 hours now. No snarky comments because I wouldn't be here if I knew how to figure this out. I need some help understanding the mistakes.

UPDATE2:
     import java.util.Scanner;

```
 public class NewClass1 {
     public static void main(String args[]) {              
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

         System.out.print("Enter a decimal value (0 to 15): ");
         int decimal = input.nextInt();


         if (decimal <= 15 && decimal  >= 10) {
              System.out.println("The hex value is " + (char)decimal );
         }

         else if (decimal  < 10 && decimal  >= 0) {
                 System.out.println("The hex value is " + decimal );
         }

         else {
             System.out.println("Invalid input");
        }
     }
 }
```

RULE1 works but produces no character/letter from a number. Do I have to set it to a variable?

UPDATE3:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NewClass1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {              
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a decimal value (0 to 15): ");
        int decimal = input.nextInt();

   // RULE1
        if (decimal <= 15 && decimal  >= 10) {
            int value = decimal - 10 + 10;
             System.out.println("The hex value is " + (char)value );
        }
   // RULE2
        else if (decimal  < 10 && decimal  >= 0) {
                System.out.println("The hex value is " + decimal );
        }
   // RULE3
        else {
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
        }
    }
}
```

I feel that I am close but the result is still invalid for RULE1

UPDATE4: Working version.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {              
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a decimal value (0 to 15): ");
        int decimal = input.nextInt();


        if (decimal <= 15 && decimal  >= 10) {
            int value = ('A' + decimal - 10);
            System.out.println("The hex value is " + (char)value );
        }

        else if (decimal  <= 10 && decimal  >= 0) {
                System.out.println("The hex value is " + decimal );
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
        }
    }
}
```

Works as intended now. Thank you all! Thank you Pham Trung.

Comment: What do you currently think `charAt` does?

Comment: I 'thought' it was suppose to summon a character/symbol that corresponds with its numerical counterpart.

Comment: Nope, it returns the character itself. So "15".charAt(0) = '1', but '1' isn't 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of read in a String:

```
    String decimal = input.nextLine();

// RULE1 
    char ch = decimal.charAt(0);
```

Just read in the integer:

```
   int ch = input.nextInt();
```

Because, when you read in as String, for example, "15", as the result, the first character will be `1`, similarly, whenever input number is bigger than 9, your `char ch` is always `1`

For your update in Rule 1, you need to do this:

```
  System.out.println("The hex value is " + (char)(value + 'A'));
```

Because, for 'A', the equivalent integer value is 65, so the above trick will help you. More details [here](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: Oh... That clears up that issue. Lend me some time to rework and figure out if there are other road-blocks

Comment: I've updated my response if you could please take a peek. Ty.

Comment: `if (decimal <= 15 && decimal  >= 10) {
                int value = ('A' + decimal - 10);
                 System.out.println("The hex value is " + (char)value );`                                        I don't quite understand how to make my comment look like code but this is my version, that I messed around with. This works too but yours looks more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Use the JDK, especially [`java.lang.String.parseInt(String s)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) and [`java.lang.Integer.toHexString(int i)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString-int-). Both are basic methods of the JDK. There is no need to fiddle which `char`s.

```
String[] sa = new String[]{"-1", "0", "1", "11", "15", "31"};
for (String s : sa) {
    int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
    if (i > 0 && i <= 15) {
        System.out.println("hex(" + s + ")= " + Integer.toHexString(i));
    } else {
        System.err.println("invalid input: " + s);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
invalid input: -1
invalid input: 0
hex(1)= 1
hex(11)= b
hex(15)= f
invalid input: 31
```

Comment: " No special `toHexStrings` `cases` or `arrays`." and I'm not far enough in  the book to understand `parse`

Comment: I hate the questions that don't allow you to use even the most basic tools :(

Comment: @ChrisRedfieldea If you are using `Scanner`, just using `nextInt`.

Comment: I was confused about `charAt(0)` but Fame and Kiril cleared up that portion. I'm just trying to figure the rest out, hoping I can get it myself. =/

Comment: Updated my response. I don't see in the book how I can get the character/letter for the `decimal` input.

Comment: `int value = decimal - 'A' + 10;` produces a character but not what I want.

Comment: What do you want to tell me with your last comment?

Answer (score 0):

`decimal.charAt(0);` will give you the first symbol of the input. So if you enter "12", the result will be just "1". You can use the `nextInt()` method of the `Scanner` classs.

To convert from dec to hex you can use the `Integer.toHexString()` method. There is no need to do hacky things like `+'A'`...

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up for me.  Lend me some time to rework and figure out if there are other road-blocks. Thank you, sir.

Comment: I've updated my response if you could please take a peek. Ty.

Comment: I have figured it out with the help you and others have provided.  'No special 'toHexStrings' 'cases' or 'arrays.' I had to use the basics of the basics but it has been solved under set requirements.